# Auto discovery of Prometheus metric endpoint in docker swarm

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, prometheus

I can set `static_configs` to provide metric endpoints to Prometheus. Is there a way to dynamically set metric endpoint in Docker swarm. For example, can we provide some label in `docker-compose.yaml` file which helps Prometheus to auto-discover metrics endpoint?

```
myApp:
  image: ...
  lables:
    prom/scrape: true # something like this
    prom/port: 3000

....
```

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus has no native service discovery support for Docker Swarm (unlike, for example, [Kubernetes service discovery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config)).

However, for auto-discovering any metric endpoints in Docker Swarm, you can use the generic [file service discovery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config) mechanism. It works by using a file that contains the desired metric endpoints. Prometheus performs a disk watch on this file and applies any changes dynamically. That means, you can update the file at runtime and Prometheus will immediately sync with it.

There is a [file service discovery integration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config) for Docker Swarm named [prometheus-swarm-discovery](https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/prometheus-swarm-discovery). This tool should be able to dynamically write the file that is used by Prometheus file service discovery, so you don't have to implement this logic yourself.